# Accessing elasticsearch outside of localhost

Tags: elasticsearch

Elastic-search: Installed on windows server 2012 running windows 10

I have been working with elasticsearch on localhost as I get familiar with it.
 Now, that I am familiar with it I have started up a Windows Server and installed elastic search on that machine.
But, now I can't find documentation to access Elatic-search without using localhost.
If somebody can point me in the right direction it would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html) is the page you are after. Dont forget the security implications of having an ES server accessible from outside your network as there is no access controls for ES.